# Chrome is requesting HTTPS suddenly and I can't log into admin area

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, https, hsts

I recently moved a wordpress site from one hostgator account to another.  It's now an addon domain.  For the last couple days everything was working fine.

Then suddenly Chrome started giving me this error when I tried to reach my admin area:
[image]

Proceeding didn't help either as I don't have an SSL, so it returns a 404.
[image]

In fact it doesn't matter what URL hijinks I play, any time I access the admin area it tries to use HTTPS.

This is only on Chrome.  It appears that Chrome is requesting an HTTPS address.  I've tried commenting out all the https code in wp-login.php but no dice.

I've tried uninstalling Chrome, clearing cookies, etc.  No good.

I'm at my wit's end.

EDIT: I've tried disabling every plugin (via cPanel) and narrowed it down to WooCommerce? I've been using it for ages...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)

Comment: I believe it has something to do with WooCommerce

Comment: possible duplicate of [All localhost http links are redirecting to https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595740/all-localhost-http-links-are-redirecting-to-https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug of Chrome v44. Look at this [article](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-44-sending-https-header-by-mistake-breaking-web-applications-everywhere/), and this is a WordPress plugin to fix this issue (at this moment):

https://github.com/IshYoBoy/aaa-ishyoboy-google-chrome-44-ssl-fix

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Clear your cache and cookies both on browser and on windows(if you're on that platform) %temp% (clear everything there)
2. Disable your network, check your system time settings make sure its correct
3. Reboot your system
4. try accessing the website using Https:// instead of Http://

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours of searching I found this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/site-broken-in-chrome-ssl-issue/page/2

Turns out the new beta version of Chrome and the wp is_SSL function aren't playing nice and it causes all kinds of havoc.   WooCommerce uses this extensively so it would seem like it's the problem (but it's not).  A lot of people are having the same issue.

A user there posted a solution but it didn't work for me.  I'm going to just wait it out.