# All localhost http links are redirecting to https

Tags: php, wordpress, http, https, xampp

I am stuck up with a Strange problem. I am a php beginner All my php files link, Image source, stylesheet are pointing to Https even though in code its http. My Web page is working fine in Firefox but i am facing this issue in Chrome. 
Example
When i view page source in chrome i get this code

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jshop-style-css'  href='https://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/themes/jshop/style.css?ver=4.2.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

whereas in Firefox i get

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jshop-style-css'  href='http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/themes/jshop/style.css?ver=4.2.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I am running my application on Xampp. Could anyone help me why i am facing this issue in Chrome ?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/https-everywhere/gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp?hl=en ?

Comment: Your original snippets show the root of the problem, before your edit. `href="//example.com/some/path/and/file.css` automatically resolves to whatever protocol you are currently using. So, if something redirects from http to https, those css assets will also come from https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday. It was an issue with using an outdated WooCommerce and Chrome Version 44.0.2403.89 (Latest version). It was forcing https for some reason. I am not sure if this is your issue, but I just updated to the newest version of WooCommere and it fixed it for me.

Comment: 2.3.12 has this Fix - Fixed Google Chrome forcing to use SSL. This can cause some issues on websites behind load balancers or reverse proxies. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe woocommerce does some work with your .htaccess that you may not have known about, I assume it does this in order to force the use of SSL.